# WebServices client in java?

Tags: web-services

I would like have a solution for creating a WebServices client and it needs to consume the Services which already existed.
I have code this from Netbeans ide but my requirement is the wsdl url must be a dynamic one and more specific it needs to fetch from .xml,please suggest me to do that dynamic..cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a Java EE application you can create a web service client in Netbeans. Otherwise you need to code it on your own or use a external tool or library.

Comment: Hi Daniel thnx for suggestion and i am going to doing this in swing application not any EE App and can u pls name the tools or libraries.Thanks in advance

Comment: KSOAP2 is a library you can use with SOAP-services

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to parse the XML and read the WSDL URL from it, you can find in the net for how to read the data from the XML
2. Once done,using the URL you got from the XML you can call the service endpoint (The code you have already)

Comment: my requirement is like i need a WebServices client which takes the wsdl url from another xml or any other file or from registry if uts windows

Comment: You are storing the WSDL URL in a file right(XML or any type).So your code read the WSDL url from the file and proceed for invocation, is that you want?

Comment: no, at runtime i would like to get the url.like as many times as url configuration and may times using.Now I can able to config one time and using many times

Comment: see,your program will read the URL at runtime only.Please ellobarte your requirement, what does mean that you are able to configure one time and using many times

Comment: i need to make my web service client on  the fly

Comment: So,you need to have one utility class, which will read the WSDL URL either from the files or from the console and generate the required client stubs. For generating the client stubs you can use any of the wsdl2java utilities.Note even if you change the WSDL URL,your program will read that too and generate the WS client code out of it.

Comment: Exactly..Will you  please suggest me more tools

Comment: There are many utilities available to convert WSDL into JAVA, Java 6 having "wsimport" and "wsgen" , you can apache axis , apache rampart, apache CXF.. What you have to do in your utility code is to read the URL dynamically and pass it to any of the utilties above. I'm not mentioning how to do that, you can study on the above in the net,there are lot of examples available..

Comment: Thanks alot for your valuable suggestions